# Python csv.writer control precision

Tags: python, csv, format, precision

i'm using the standard csv.writer like so

```
wr = csv.writer(f,csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
wr.writerows(output)
```

and i would like to be able to format the csv file so that every column has %3.4e. output is a 2 dimensional list. right now, it seems to be writing it out in whatever precisions the values were stored in, which can be variable. i also don't know at code time the size of each dimension, specifically, how many elements are in each row, so i can't simply write out a big format string. is there a simple way to use the csv.writer to just write every numeric value with a certain precision?

Comment: Seems like you code convert the numeric values to strings yourself formatted the way you want, and then output those. Without more code, it's difficult to be more specific.

Comment: well i'm just filling output from another file and some calculations. it's just a 2d array basically, all of floats. how do i go about formatting it before i write it? i'm somewhat new to python, and i tried to create a formatted list with generic parameters for size but it didn't work.

Comment: OK, in that case, @achampion's answer is what you'll need to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still output on arbitrary length list with format strings, though you probably want to use csv.QUOTE_NONE:

```
wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
for i in output:
    wr.writerow(['{:3.4e}'.format(x) for x in i])
```