# Issue creating CSV from Access database

Tags: python, csv, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I have a database in MS Access. I am trying to export one column from one table to a CSV file, with Python using pypyodbc.
From the CSV file obtained, there are no commas in numbers greater than 1. Any idea to solve?

Screen from MS Access:
[MS Access database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUe12.png)

Screen from the obtained CSV:
[CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgyZ5.png)

Code:

```
import pypyodbc
import csv
import os
from pathlib import Path
import re

data_folder1 = Path("/Users/sfulc/Desktop/FileProva/")
data_folder2 = Path("/Users/sfulc/Desktop/FileOutput/")

for filename in os.listdir("/Users/sfulc/Desktop/FileProva/"):
    file1 = r"Dbq=" + os.path.abspath(data_folder1 / filename) + r";"
    file2 = re.sub("mdb", "csv", os.path.abspath(data_folder2 / filename))
    pypyodbc.lowercase = False
    conn = pypyodbc.connect(r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" + file1)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT LoadValue FROM OriginalData");
    with open(file2, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            writer.writerow(row)
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: This normally is a `Locale` problem, it depend on the Language/Locale settings. What language are you using?

Comment: It's the _csv.writer_ playing games with you, not _Access_.

Comment: Print the row to see whats there. Maybe convert the item to string first.

Comment: @piertoni Italian

Comment: Good suggestions from @Gustav and @Colin-Curtain
1. to understand if is a csv issue try instead of `writerow` to print the content and check what is inside.
2. Play with csv, try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861420/python-csv-writer-control-precision

Comment: @ColinCurtain If I print I obtain this: 
(0.1589555,)
(0.4153565,)
(0.7951628,)
(1.184598,)
(1.489722,)
(1.732026,) ......

Comment: If I try to convert the item to string the result is this: (,0,.,0,4,5,7,9,5,5,2,",",)
(,0,.,1,5,8,9,5,5,5,",",)
(,0,.,4,1,5,3,5,6,5,",",)
(,0,.,7,9,5,1,6,2,8,",",)
(,1,.,1,8,4,5,9,8,",",)

Comment: If I open the CSV file with a text editor it is displayed correctly, so the problem is with excel. Do you have any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: convert the item to string like this:  i= 0.1234 then next line, s = str(i)  this gives '0.1234'

Comment: Importing csv into excel. try the instructions here to import the numbers as text: https://planergy.com/blog/open-csv-in-excel/